# Write to Google Sheets with Powershell (error System.Net.WebException 401 Unauthorized )

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script, webrequest, invoke-webrequest

That Powershell script intents to write to Google Sheets considering the user is already logged on his/her Google account on the Browser, but it throws the error `System.Net.WebException`. Message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
In C:\Users\F76254C\Desktop\Nova pasta\Batch files\Available Projects\Latam HIL Lab Menu\libs\GAS.ps1:141 character:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $GoogleWebAppURL -Method POST ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I tested this code using a Google Web App deployed with my personal Google account (Who has access to the app: Anyone) and it works fine with no error, but I need to make it working using a Google Web App deployed with my professional Google account (Who has access to the app: Anyone within the company).

```
$GoogleWebAppURL = 'URL_DEPLOYED_FROM_PROFESSIONAL_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT'

$Column1Name = 'Computer'
$Column1Value = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$Column2Name = 'IP Address'
$Column2Value = (Test-Connection -ComputerName ::1 -Count 1|select ipv4address).ipv4address

$Column3Name = 'OS Version'
$Column3Value = "$([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major)`.$([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Minor)`.$([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Build)`.$([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Revision)"

$Column4Name = 'Uptime'
$Column4Value = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select lastbootuptime).lastbootuptime

$postParams = @{$Column1Name=$Column1Value;$Column2Name=$Column2Value;$Column3Name=$Column3Value;$Column4Name=$Column4Value}
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $GoogleWebAppURL -Method POST -Body $postParams

Write-Host `"$Column1Name=$Column1Value"&"$Column2Name=$Column2Value"&"$Column3Name=$Column3Value"&"$Column4Name=$Column4Value`"
```

Comment: You would need drive access scope.

Comment: @TheMaster, I have searched about that after your comment and I got even more confused. I saw a lot of unknown terms like gcloud, service account, json and I am quite unsure that comes first. would you mind to give more clue?

Comment: @TheMaster, why that script just work fine like it is when ran with my personal account?

Comment: See the tag info page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script-web-application/info @Tanaike  github resource there explains 401 : Reading it again, 401 would mean Bad access token. I'm unfamiliar with powershell though